# Symfony2 composer vendor namspace not found

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces, composer-php

I'm trying to use a vendor lib that I created my self. For now I am not able to put it in GIT or SVN so I am trying to get it running without.

This is my directory structure(borrowed from an answer below):

```
vendor/
    ISTlibraries/
        Saml2Handler/
            src/
                Saml2Handler/
```

In my composer.json I have added

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/",
        "Saml2Handler": "vendor/ISTlibraries/Saml2Handler/src/"
    }
},
```

vendor/ISTlibraries/Saml2Handler/src/ is the path to my sourcecode. The class I am trying to get is called Saml2Controller which have this namespace defined

```
namespace Saml2Handler;
```

When I try from inside my symfony2 controller to initiate the class I get an error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Saml2Handler\Saml2Controller' not found in ...
```

In the controller I try a simple new Saml2Controller and I have written

```
use Saml2Handler\Saml2Controller;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: is there a file called `Saml2Controller.php` in the directory which you have defined?

Comment: yes in src theres a Saml2Controller.php and the class inside is called Saml2Controller with namespace Saml2Handler;

Comment: have you run `composer install` ?

Comment: Is there someway I can confirm that the autoloader have indeed been updated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The error is expected. I believe that you need the following directory structure:

```
vendor/
    ISTlibraries/
        Saml2Handler/
            src/
                Saml2Handler/ <--- you don't have this
                    Saml2Controller.php
```

... in order to have `namespace Saml2Handler` within your `Saml2Handler.php`.

Comment: This is how my structure is. Though I don't have any Saml2Handler.php file... Do I need that?

Comment: Examples in `https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0` end `psr-0` namespaces with "\\". Can you try that?

Comment: Finally! That looks like it fixed it. Can you explain to me why?? I'm having a hard time to understand it.